# Sum a Total of Multiple Columns in Each Row in a given Range via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of items with data from Column L to X and I would like to add the total of each row in the above range in the corresponding row in column K.

In order to do that I wrote the following code but there is no output and no errors:

```
Sub Sum_multiple_columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim destinationLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim TotalCoverage As Double
    Dim rng As Range, MyResultsRng As Range
    Const FirstCol As Long = 10 ' "L"
    Const LastCol As Long = 22 ' "X"
    Const TotalCoverageColumn As Long = 9
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    destinationLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To destinationLastRow
        Set MyResultsRng = ws.Range("K" & i)
        For Each cell In MyResultsRng
            Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, FirstCol), ws.Cells(i, LastCol))
            TotalCoverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Value)
        Next
    Next
    With MyResultsRng
        .Value = TotalCoverage
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
     End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for pointing me towards the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Columns 10:22 is columns J:V, you should use 12:24 for L:X.  Or use `ws.Cells(i, "L")` instead of `ws.Cells(i, FirstCol)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sum Rows of Adjacent Columns

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumRowsOfAdjacentColumns()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Master" ' Worksheet Name
    Const fRow As Long = 5 ' First Row
    Const sCols As String = "L:X" ' Source (Sum) Columns
    Const lrCol As String = "A" ' Last Row Column
    Const tCol As String = "K" ' Totals (Destination) Column
    
    ' Create a reference to the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Totals Range ('trg').
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = lRow - fRow + 1
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Cells(fRow, tCol).Resize(rCount)
    'Debug.Print "Totals Range Address:     " & trg.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim srrg As Range ' Current Source Row (Sum) Range
    Dim tCell As Range ' Current Totals Cell
    Dim TotalCoverage As Variant ' Current Total ***
    Dim sCell As Range ' Current Source Cell (If Error Values)
    Dim tSum As Double ' Current Subtotal (If Error Values)
    For Each tCell In trg.Cells
        ' Use the current Totals Cell ('tCell') to create a reference
        ' to the current Source Row (Sum) Range ('srrg').
        Set srrg = tCell.EntireRow.Columns(sCols)
        'Debug.Print "Source Row Range Address: " & srrg.Address(0, 0)
        ' If there are error values, 'WorksheetFunction.Sum' will raise
        ' an error, while 'Application.Sum' will return an error value.
        ' Hence the previous declaration 'As Variant' is necessary ***.
        TotalCoverage = Application.Sum(srrg)
        If IsNumeric(TotalCoverage) Then ' no error values
            tCell.Value = TotalCoverage
        Else ' there are error values
            tSum = 0
            For Each sCell In srrg.Cells
                ' Sum-up only numeric values.
                If IsNumeric(sCell) Then
                    tSum = tSum + sCell.Value
                End If
            Next sCell
            tCell.Value = tSum
        End If
    Next tCell
    
    ' Formatting the cells in one go is more efficient (faster).
    With trg
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        '.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You update the value of `TotalCoverage` on each pass in the loop.  After the loop has finished you put the final value of `TotalCoverage` onto the sheet.

As it is your code didn't run as you've not declared the `cell` variable - one of the benefits of having `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.  Reminds you to declare all variables.

With data going from L5:X13 it places the result in cell K13.  To get it to place a total on each row use the code below.
Only difference is where the two `Next` statements are.  I've also declared `cell` and added which loop the `Next` belongs to (i.e. `Next cell`).

```
Sub Sum_multiple_columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim destinationLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim TotalCoverage As Double
    Dim rng As Range, MyResultsRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Const FirstCol As Long = 12 ' "L"
    Const LastCol As Long = 24 ' "X"
    Const TotalCoverageColumn As Long = 9
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    destinationLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To destinationLastRow
        Set MyResultsRng = ws.Range("K" & i)
        For Each cell In MyResultsRng
            Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, FirstCol), ws.Cells(i, LastCol))
            TotalCoverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Value)
            With cell
                .Value = TotalCoverage
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Name = "Calibri"
                .NumberFormat = "0.00"
             End With
        Next cell
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit:  Have also changed `With MyResultRng` to `With Cell`.